# Are there compatibility restrictions about remotes for dropper posts and suspension locks?

Tags: compatibility, suspension, dropper

I consider adding an handle bar remote for a bike with a front-suspension fork. Given the bike has already a dropper post, I was thinking to add a dual "dropper/suspension" remote.

I noticed that the specs for remotes (either for dropper posts or suspensions) rarely mention the amount of travel for the cables, so I was wondering: is it because the travel is somehow "standardised" (for dropper posts it's only a simple pull and if it's blocked from the post itself, no issue, but the actuation is different for suspension locks as they need to to be locked in specific positions), or is there a implicit requirement to use the compatible remote?

To make the question more complete: some suspension remotes also allow to have an intermediate position. Is this also specific to each brand of suspension?

Comment: Big +1 from me. The basic way it works is dropper remotes are mostly standardized, but I have seen combos that don't quite work, and it can be hard to predict unless one simply does whatever the mfg says in terms of pairing. Lockouts tend to be pretty brand specific afaik.